# Why do I keep getting the 405 error (Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL.) when the POST method is correctly set up?

Tags: python, flask

I am learning Flask and I've incurred into a supposedly beginners error:

> Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

The thing is that, even though I reduce the code into something really simple, I can't find it. As far as I can see, the POST method is correctly set up (I will use comments to explain it).

The files are:

**flaskblog.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect, request
from forms import RegistrationForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '5791628bb0b13ce0c676dfde280ba245'

@app.route("/")
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST']) # As one can see, the POST method is written there.
def home():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    return render_template('home.html', title='Home', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action=""> # The POST method is written there as well.
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.username.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')
```

I get the error when I submit the form, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're **not distinguishing** between `GET` and `POST` requests appropriately in your `home` route. Flask *defaults* the incoming request, from the client, as a `GET` request since your definitions are off. However, this is an issue because the incoming request is actually a `POST` request as we can see from your form:

```
<form method="POST" action=""> # The POST method is written there as well.
```

Perhaps you could try modifying your `home` route to handle both `POST`/`GET` requests approriately, something along the lines of:

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    # POST request
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for(<route>)) #route to be rendered if form properly validates
    # GET request
    return render_template('home.html', title='Home', form=form)
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer Nathan. I copy and paste your code (also, I change <route> by 'home') and got the same error.

Comment: You don't want to render the `home.html` template for both `GET` and `POST` requests. You need another route, i.e. page to render, by changing `<route>` to `home` you are back where you started where both post/get requests render this form which is incorrect and leaves flask unable to distinguish what you want.

Comment: I believe your home.html should actually be a signup.html and your home.html should have different content. Does that make sense?